# In order to test a function with unit testing, does it need to have a return value?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am new to python and am trying to learn about unit testing. I am using pytest to run some unit tests on my code. Something very similar to this example:

```
def test_calc_total():
    total = mathlib.calc_total(4,5)
    assert total == 9
```

I may be incorrect here, but I am learning that in order for your function be testable, it will have to return a value. Is this true for all unit tests?

I am finding that the majority of my functions are not able to be tested, since they don't have a return value. I am creating a ticket tracking system and storing the ticket information in a dataframe. Here is a portion of *TicketDF* class:

```
class TicketDF():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    def __init__(self, configParser):
        self.populateFilePaths(configParser)
        self.populateAttributes(configParser)
        self.populateTable()

    def populateTable(self):
        if self.doesFileExistAndNotEmpty(self.ticketCSVFilePath):
            self.df = pd.read_csv(self.ticketCSVFilePath, converters={'Comments':literal_eval}) #, 'Attachments':literal_eval})
            self.df.set_index('Ticket ID', inplace=True)

    def populateAttributes(self, configParser):
        self.ticketAttributes =  configParser.getTicketAttributes()

    def populateFilePaths(self, configParser):
        self.ticketCSVFilePath = configParser.getTicketsCSVPath()

    def doesFileExistAndNotEmpty(self, filepath):
        if os.path.exists(filepath) and os.path.getsize(filepath) > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getTicketDF(self):
        return self.df

    def addTicketToDF(self, data):
        df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = self.ticketAttributes)
        df.set_index('Ticket ID', inplace=True)
        self.df = self.df.append(df)
        self.saveDFToCSV()
```

As you can see, the majority of the functions, even the ones not shown, do not have return values. Is it best practice to write code so that all functions have a return value? Or is there another way to test functions without a return value?

Comment: these methods are changing the state of the object or its properties so you can verify the values, the changed state

Comment: Pure functions - that is, functions with output _only_ determined by their input - are the easiest thing to test. You should strive to write these types of functions when possible because you can make much stronger guarantees about behaviors.

Comment: To write a unit test, you need observable, verifiable, deterministic side effects of calling the function. There does not need to be a return value.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. This is helpful.

@erip The output being the return value?

Comment: Pure functions exist outside the world of computers, but yes - in the context of programming, the output would be the value returned. The bottom line is: keep data as immutable as possible, try to return values, and minimize side-effects; you'll have a happier time writing programs. :-)

Comment: Fairly good reading in the results searching with `python unittest test method changes instance attribute site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @erip Thank you. So in this case or any case for that matter, would it be wise to modify my program so that instead of keeping a dataframe in the class, **self.df**, I then am passing and returning the dataframe from function to function? This way the functions are immutable.

Comment: @wwii could you please link the questions you're referring to? I am not finding many from that query.

Comment: It depends on a couple of things and is ultimately a very philosophical discussion. What you're asking is basically "should I prefer object-orientation" or "should I prefer functional programming?" There's a place for both - I encourage you to read about both and determine that for yourself. I lean more toward FP (so functions, their composition, and immutability) - that doesn't make it more or less right.

Comment: @erip I see what you're saying. I will do some digging on that.Thank you all for the responses!

Comment: I took your question as being more generic in the context of `trying to learn about unit testing` and thought that reading through other related SO Q&A's would give you some perspective on testing methods that change state in a class instance or functions that don't return anything but have side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Testing a function depends on the ability to

1. observe changes caused by the function to the state of the program or
2. access the return value of the function.

So, if a function's behavior changes the state of a program and we need to test this behavior, then we need to be able to access the part of the state that is changed to test the corresponding behavior.  Such tests may not always rely on the return value of the function.  Hence, functions need not return value to be testable but they do need to expose information pertaining to their behaviors that need to be tested.

For more on this aspect of testing, read about test doubles.  "Using test doubles" chapter about indirect inputs and outputs in "xUnit Test Patterns" book is a good reference.

Comment: Keep in mind that testing the results of side-effects can be _very challenging_. In python there's no such concept as privacy, but for other languages this is a huge hang-up.

Comment: Thank you @Venkatesh!

Answer (score 1):

No, it can have a side-effect and you test that side effect.

For example, consider a function which writes to a file. Errors are reported via exceptions. It has nothing to return. The unit test would invoke the function and check that the relevant file has been written to, as well as to induce various exceptions.

Another example is a method call which changes the state of an object. You call the method and check that the object's state has changed.